# Using getter and setter methods inside a class in my main class

Tags: java

I have to write a program that writes a class called "Employee" that holds information about an employees name and salary. Then I need to use that information inside my main class to set the employee information then get the employee information and print it to the screen, but I have no idea how to access my information inside my "Employee" class to use in my "main" class. Here's what I have in my "Employee" class.

```
package classwork6_1;

public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private float salary;

    public String getName()  {        
        return name;        
    }

    public float getSalary() {          
        return salary;     
    }

    public void setName(String name){
     this.name = name;          
    }

    public void setSalary(float salary){
        this.salary = salary;        
    }     
}
```

Comment: And what is in your `main`? Where is the problem?

Comment: Share your main code

Comment: I'm also new to stack overflow, how can I upload my main, do I just edit my original post or do I create a new one?

Comment: @MattL. when you create the Employee class. You can create a corresponding Main class and in the class import your Employee class and instantiate the Employee class and set its instance variables and then get them in print statement.

Comment: Thank you guys, this really helped get me going!

Answer (score 2):

In your main class, instantiate `Employee`, and call the setters:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setName("Matt");
emp.setSalary(50000);
```

Then just print it using the getters:

```
System.out.println("Name: " + emp.getName() + ", salary: " + emp.getSalary());
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just follow these simple steps:**

After creating an instance of Employee

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
```

You want to set the values using the `setters`. For example:

```
employee.setName("John");
employee.setSalary(100f);
```

After that you can get the values back using the `getters`. For example:

```
String name = employee.getName();
float salary = employee.getSalary();
```

**Improve your class by adding a constructor!**

In addition, I would include a `constructor` to your class. For example:

```
public Employee(String name, float salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

Now you can do the following to make an instance of your class:

```
Employee employee = new Employee("John", 100f);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Main class should be something like this

```
import classwork6_1.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee  e=new Employee();
        e.setSalary(2000f);
        e.setName("Gagan");
        System.out.println("Name: " + e.getName() + " Salary : " + e.getSalary());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to access my information inside my "Employee" class to use in my "main" class.

1. Instantiate an `Employee` object.
2. Invoke methods on that object.

Here is a complete example of your class. See the `public static void main` method to see how steps 1 & 2 above work. Other correct Answers on this page show this as well.

By the way, in real work, never use `float`/`Float` or `double`/`Double` for money where accuracy matters. [Floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) technology [trades away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of execution. The [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class is the opposite, slow but accurate.

```
// Example app for Answer in Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107000/642706
// Simple example, not meant for use in production.
// Caution: *Not* thread-safe.
public class Employee {

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal salary;

    public Employee ( String name , BigDecimal salary ) {
        this.setName( name );
        this.setSalary( salary );
    }

    public String getName ( ) {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName ( String name ) {
        // … add your data validation checks here. Example: Strings that are too short or too long.
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary ( ) {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary ( BigDecimal salary ) {
        // … add your data validation checks here. Example: Numbers that are negative, too big, or too small.
        salary.setScale( 2 , RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN ); // Round to the penny, using Banker’s Rounding.
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void giveRaise ( int percentagePoints ) {
        BigDecimal percentageAsDecimalFraction = new BigDecimal( percentagePoints ).divide( new BigDecimal( 100 ) );
        BigDecimal mulitiplier = new BigDecimal( "1" ).add( percentageAsDecimalFraction );
        BigDecimal newSalary = this.getSalary().multiply( mulitiplier ).setScale( 2 , RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN );  // Round to the penny, using Banker’s Rounding.
        this.setSalary( newSalary );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( ) {
        return "Employee{ " +
                "name='" + this.getName() + '\'' +
                " | salary=" + this.getSalary() +  // In real work we would *not* be dumping sensitive private data like salary that might end up in logs or other insecure data-sinks. 
                " }";
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Employee x = new Employee( "Alice" , new BigDecimal( "1234.56" ) );
        Employee y = new Employee( "Bob" , new BigDecimal( "678.12" ) );

        System.out.println( x );
        System.out.println( y );

        x.giveRaise( 10 );
        y.giveRaise( 5 );

        System.out.println( "After raises." );
        System.out.println( x );
        System.out.println( y );
    }
}
```

When run.

> Employee{ name='Alice' | salary=1234.56 }
>
> Employee{ name='Bob' | salary=678.12 }
>
> After raises.
>
> Employee{ name='Alice' | salary=1358.02 }
>
> Employee{ name='Bob' | salary=712.03 }